# Why are areas targets get mixed up and overlap in unity when running the project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm working on "Indoor Navigation" project using AR with Vuforia, I have scanned the map using "Vuforia Area Target Creator" Application. I have imported the area targets to unity and I have created NavMesh. I'm following this: https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/multiple-area-targets. I'm also created NavMeshAgent and destination but when I run the project, area targets overlap and NavMeshAgent can't pass through, What is the problem ??
[image: My Area Targets]

[image: The Area Targets before run]

[image: The Area Targets after run]

MultiArea code (as above link explained):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class MultiArea : MonoBehaviour
{
    #region PUBLIC_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    public bool hideAugmentationsWhenNotTracked = true;
    
    #endregion PUBLIC_MEMBER_VARIABLES
    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARS

    /// <summary>
    /// Trackable poses relative to the MultiArea root
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Matrix4x4> mPoses = new Dictionary<string, Matrix4x4>();
    private bool m_Tracked = false;

    #endregion PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARS
    #region UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    var areaTargets = GetComponentsInChildren<AreaTargetBehaviour>(includeInactive: true);
    foreach (var at in areaTargets)
    {
        // Remember the relative pose of each AT to the group root node
        var matrix = GetFromToMatrix(at.transform, transform);
        mPoses[at.TargetName] = matrix;
        Debug.Log("Original pose: " + at.TargetName + "\n" + matrix.ToString(""));

        // Detach augmentation and re-parent it under the group root node
        for (int i = at.transform.childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var child = at.transform.GetChild(i);
            child.SetParent(transform, worldPositionStays: true);
        }

        if (hideAugmentationsWhenNotTracked)
        {
            ShowAugmentations(false);
        }
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!VuforiaApplication.Instance.IsRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Find current "best tracked" Area Target
    var atb = GetBestTrackedAreaTarget();
    if (!atb)
    {
        if (m_Tracked)
        {
            m_Tracked = false;
            if (hideAugmentationsWhenNotTracked)
            {
                ShowAugmentations(false);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!m_Tracked)
    {
        m_Tracked = true;
        ShowAugmentations(true);
    }

    if (GetGroupPoseFromAreaTarget(atb, out Matrix4x4 groupPose))
    {
        // set new group pose
        transform.position = groupPose.GetColumn(3);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(groupPose.GetColumn(2), groupPose.GetColumn(1));
    }
}

#endregion UNITY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



#region PRIVATE_METHODS

private void ShowAugmentations(bool show)
{
    var renderers = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
    foreach (var rnd in renderers)
    {
        rnd.enabled = show;
    }
}

private AreaTargetBehaviour GetBestTrackedAreaTarget()
{
    var trackedAreaTargets = GetTrackedAreaTargets(includeLimited: true);
    if (trackedAreaTargets.Count == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // look for extended/tracked targets
    foreach (var at in trackedAreaTargets)
    {
        if (at.TargetStatus.Status == Status.TRACKED ||
            at.TargetStatus.Status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            return at;
        }
    }

    // if no target in EXT/TRACKED was found,
    // then fallback to any other target
    // i.e. including LIMITED ones;
    // just report the first in the list
    return trackedAreaTargets[0];
}

private List<AreaTargetBehaviour> GetTrackedAreaTargets(bool includeLimited = false)
{
    var trackedTargets = new List<AreaTargetBehaviour>();
    var activeAreaTargets = FindObjectsOfType<AreaTargetBehaviour>();
    foreach (var target in activeAreaTargets)
    {
        if (target.enabled &&
            (target.TargetStatus.Status == Status.TRACKED ||
            target.TargetStatus.Status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED ||
            (includeLimited && target.TargetStatus.Status == Status.LIMITED)))
        {
            trackedTargets.Add(target);
        }
    }
    return trackedTargets;
}

private bool GetGroupPoseFromAreaTarget(AreaTargetBehaviour atb, out Matrix4x4 groupPose)
{
    groupPose = Matrix4x4.identity;
    if (mPoses.TryGetValue(atb.TargetName, out Matrix4x4 areaTargetToGroup))
    {
        // Matrix of group root node w.r.t. AT
        var groupToAreaTarget = areaTargetToGroup.inverse;

        // Current atb matrix
        var areaTargetToWorld = atb.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        groupPose = areaTargetToWorld * groupToAreaTarget;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static Matrix4x4 GetFromToMatrix(Transform from, Transform to)
{
    var m1 = from ? from.localToWorldMatrix : Matrix4x4.identity;
    var m2 = to ? to.worldToLocalMatrix : Matrix4x4.identity;
    return m2 * m1;
}

#endregion PRIVATE_METHODS
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably set the area target as static am I right?
the area target should move always so they can't be static even if you use a navmesh.
try to change it to "Navigation static" and then bake again using the "Navigation" menu.
Link for reference:
https://library.vuforia.com/develop-area-targets/using-unitys-navmesh-navigation-area-targets

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31835036)